# selecting some specific xml elements to list of anonymous objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have an xml document with main XElement "details" and several "detail" XElements, and for each detail Element i have also several "node" Element, this is a part of my xml  document:

```
<details>
    <detail>
      <node>
        <key>HEADER ID</key>
        <value>D10</value>
      </node>
      <node>
        <key>PRODUCT NO</key>
        <value>9671834480D04  </value>
      </node>
      <node>
        <key>WIRE (CODE)</key>
        <value>AD8</value>
      </node>
      <node>
        <key>WIRE SIZE(CODE)</key>
        <value>047</value>
      </node>
      <node>
        <key>WIRE COLOR(CODE)</key>
        <value>30</value>
      </node>
      <node>
        <key>CUT LENGTH</key>
        <value>01910</value>
      </node>
    </detail>
    <detail>
      <node>
        ...
      </node>
        ...
    </detail>
        ...
<details>
```

I am trying to transform this xml part to a list of object that contains just 3 properties correspond on "Key" and "value" elements. for example for each detail element in details and for each node element in detail i want to get just 3 nodes where the key element equals "PRODUCT NO" or "WIRE KIND(CODE)" or "CUT LENGTH"?

this is my code, it works, but i think it is not suitable for performance :

```
var champs = 
    from detail in details
    let productNo = detail.Elements("node")
        .Where(k => k.Element("key")
        .Value == "PRODUCT NO")
        .Select(v => v.Element("value").Value)
        .First()
    let wireCode = detail.Elements("node")
        .Where(k => k.Element("key").Value == "WIRE (CODE)")
        .Select(v => v.Element("value").Value)
        .First()
    let cutLength = detail.Elements("node")
        .Where(k => k.Element("key").Value == "CUT LENGTH")
        .Select(v => v.Element("value").Value)
        .First()
    select new { ProductNo = productNo, WireCode = wireCode , CutLength = cutLength };
```

i think this is an example of select n+1 issue, because for each propety i must browse all nodes, how can i do the same with one loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually think about readability before performance, unless you know you have a performance issue. But even so, you can definitely improve the code. I would consider using `ToDictionary` to convert each `detail` element into a `Dictionary<string, string>`, then you can get the bits you want:

```
var query = details.Select(d => d.Elements("node")
                                 .ToDictionary(n => n.Element("key").Value,
                                               n => n.Element("value").Value))
                   .Select(x => new { ProductNo = x["PRODUCT NO"],
                                      WireCode = x["WIRE (CODE)"],
                                      CutLength = x["CUT LENGTH"] });
```

It's then *very* easy to add extra properties as you need them.

Comment: I paste your request in linqPad and i've got this error :  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>'

Comment: I still geting the same error, is there another way without converting XElements to Dictionary ?

Comment: @younel: You shouldn't have got the same error - you should have got a slightly different error :) I've fixed a typo now, and it's working for me... this is assuming that `details` is an `IEnumerable<XElement>` where each item is a `<detail>` element.

Comment: yes it work if key element is unique, but i have multiple key elements with the same content, the query stop in ToDictionary function and throw ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added. anyway i consider the  problem has been solved. thinks

Comment: @younel: You never mentioned that, so I don't know how I was meant to guess it. You could use ToLookup instead in that case.